# how can i send my message from android client to other android client using my socket java PC server

Tags: java, android, sockets

i have my code that sucessfuly send my client message to server.. can anyone help pls ? i'm new in socket programming. i want to establish a server that sends the message of my android client to other android client... here is my code

CLIENT ANDROID :

```
package com.example.websocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chatroom extends Activity {


    public static String msgToServer = null;
    TextView uname;
    EditText in;
    Button snd;
    TextView out;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatroom);

        uname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewmynam);
        in = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);
        snd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOutput);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String urname = bundle.getString("myname");
        uname.setText(urname);

        MyClientTask clientTask = new MyClientTask();
        clientTask.execute();


    }

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            connect();
            return null;
            }

    }

    public void connect() {
        Socket sock;
        int[] allports = {1111,1919,2020};
        int portnum;

        for(int i=1;i<allports.length;i++) {
        try {

        portnum = allports[i];
        boolean socketno = Middleware.available(portnum);
        String ad = "192.168.149.1";
        if(socketno = true) {
            sock = new Socket(ad,portnum);
            while(socketno) {
                sendmsg(sock);
        }//while
         //   sock.close();
        }//if

        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }

    public void sendmsg (final Socket s) {
        snd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //boolean listening = true;
                String inmsg = ""+in.getText().toString();
                String response = "";

                msgToServer = inmsg;
                //out.append("you:"+msgToServer+"\n");

                 try {
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream inToServer = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                if(outToServer != null){
                outToServer.writeBytes(msgToServer+"\n");
                }


                 }
                 catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chatroom, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my  PC Server side :

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.*;


public class SocketServer extends Thread {

final static int _portNumber = 1919; //Arbitrary port number

      public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {
            new SocketServer().startServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I/O failure: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void startServer() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(_portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + _portNumber);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) {
                        System.out.println("Huwat huwat kang client..!");
            handleClientRequest(serverSocket);
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }

    private void handleClientRequest(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        try {
            new Thread(new ConnectionRequestHandler(serverSocket.accept())).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles client connection requests. 
     */
    public class ConnectionRequestHandler implements Runnable{
        private Socket _socket;
        private PrintWriter _out;
        private BufferedReader _in;



        public ConnectionRequestHandler(Socket socket) {
            _socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            String info;
            int maxid;

            System.out.println("Client connected to socket: " + _socket.toString()); 
            info = _socket.toString();
            //incrementing the msg_id


            try {
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                         _socket.getOutputStream()));
                _in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;



                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/finalclient","root","");
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select *from msgs order by msg_id desc");
                ResultSet r1 = st.executeQuery();
                r1.first(); // or r1.next()
                maxid = r1.getInt("msg_id") + 1;

                while ((inputLine = _in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from Client: "+inputLine);
                    out.write(inputLine);
                    try {
                        PreparedStatement st1=con.prepareStatement("insert into msgs  values(?,?,?)");
                        st1.setInt(1,maxid);
                        st1.setString(2,info);
                        st1.setString(3,inputLine);
                        int count = st1.executeUpdate ();

                        System.out.println (count + " rows were inserted to Database");

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Failed to Insert from DB"+e);
                    }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to Select from DB"+e);
            }

                } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please. I did not   look at your code yet as  i expect you to explain first what your code does or should do.

Comment: my code only sends message to server. and it is already successfuly sending.. but my problem is how to send it to other client ?

Comment: Your server is listening on 1919. Your client uses 1111, 1919 and 2020. Only 2020 is finally used in the on click handler. How could this ever work? And why this approach?

Comment: i made a program that will find available port.. and it successfuly connected to opening port.. then my only problem is how to send the message from my other client to other android client

Comment: Your program may find the available port but if someone doubts that then why not explain how your code works? Why are you posting code where you don't wanna talk about?